# Highcharts distorsion

Tags: javascript, css, macos, google-chrome, highcharts

I am experiencing strange behavior when the width of my graph is enlarged to 1727px or more.

When this happens the lines of the graph start to distort or warp.

I have tested a lot of different solutions but none of them seem to work for this.

I'm working with Highcharts and JQuery.
Using a 16-inch MacBook Pro and Chrome version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (x86_64).
This error occurs with Google Chrome. However Safari and Firefox work well.

[What i see](https://i.ibb.co/xzJFLqK/chrome-capture-3.gif)

[image: Distorsion]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqdhk1x3/)

```
document.getElementById('small').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.setSize(1726, 300);
});

document.getElementById('medium').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.setSize(1727, 300);
});

document.getElementById('large').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.setSize(1900, 300);
});

document.getElementById('xtraLarge').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.setSize(3900, 300);
});
```

Every idea is welcome.

Comment: Hi @Ralsho, It looks like a bug in Chrome. I recommend you to report an issue on the Highcharts GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: The realated GitHub post: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one answer from GitHub:

"This is more a browser SVG bug, not Highcharts itself. As far as I know, it will be fixed in the next Chrome v96 version"

I'll report the behaviour when Chrome updates to v96.
If someone thinks that there's more to test just say it, i keep testing other solutions by my own.